# *Google maps places search box function using AngularJs* is not working in my case

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have just copy-pasted the code from [Google Maps API's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform#try-it-yourself), but also Iam getting error like [As shown in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vpck.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vpck.png)...can anybody solve this.....Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not used the API Key, I had the problem earlier..Please get an **API Key,** if the same problem arises